# file_get_content don't work for special site

Tags: php, web, file-get-contents

i want to get content of https://06fazmusic.com/ but file_get_content don't work.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'follow_location' => false,
    'header' => "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8rn" .
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdchrn" .
        "Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5rn" .
        "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8" .
        "Cache-Control:max-age=0" .
        "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
    )
));


$post_url='https://06fazmusic.com/omid-called-namaze-eshgh/';
$array = get_headers($post_url);
echo file_get_contents($post_url, false, $context);
```

Comment: "_don't work_" meaning what?

Comment: please check this code.
i cant get content of this site
@kerbholz

Comment: please translate `don't work` into meaningful information.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use file_get_contents(). I used Curl type to get that page ex code is:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
echo curl_get_contents($post_url);
```

it is working Output screen shot is :
[image]

Comment: _it is working..._ Technically yes but access denied so you can't get the "real" content

Comment: When I try his code it throws this error `file_get_contents(https://www.06fazmusic.com/omid-called-namaze-eshgh/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` So I Used with Curl. @B001

Comment: how i can get this site?
it's block the bots and i can't access to details of this site